# Joomla Website - Whenever user gets a link without "www." in the URL, the website automatically redirects to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

For example, if my link is: "http://example.com/about/blahblahblah"

It automatically redirects to example.com (homepage)

On the other hand if I write http://www.example.com/about/blahblahblah - it takes the user to that specific page properly like it is intended to.

I wanted to know how I can make the first link (that is without "www." in the URL) also take the user to the specific page properly as intended.

If it helps, from what I googled so far, it seems like something that the .htaccess file can fix but I have no experience with coding in there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seem that something is wrong with your .htaccess file or server configuration.
Please check if you have renamed htaccess.txt to .htaccess and it's not altered with custom rules.

To make permanently htaccess redirects you have to add:

Force the www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Remove the www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^your-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

[Here is the complete helpful guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/www-no-www/).

Good Luck!